# Move rows of data from one workbook to another based on condition

Tags: excel, vba

k1dr0ck helped with the below code.

How could I amend this code to open the destination workbook automatically prior to running the IF statement?
I tried a few things, but the macro stops running after I use the `.Open` command.

```vb
Sub Button3_Click()

    Dim sourceWB As Workbook
    Dim sourceWS As Worksheet
    Dim destWB As Workbook
    Dim destWS As Worksheet
    Dim sourceRange As Range
    Dim destRange As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    Set sourceWB = Workbooks("Copy of Copy of Copy of Pace Duplicate Check 2023 (002).xlsm")
    Set sourceWS = sourceWB.Worksheets("PAID")
    Set destWB = Workbooks("MacroTestWorkbook.xlsm")
    Set destWS = destWB.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    lastRow = sourceWS.Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row ' Determine the last row in column J
    
    For i = lastRow To 1 Step -1 ' Loop through the range backwards to avoid skipping rows after deletion
        If sourceWS.Cells(i, "J").Value = "REMOVE" Then
            Set sourceRange = sourceWS.Rows(i)
            Set destRange = destWS.Cells(destWS.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) ' Determine the first empty row in destination sheet
            sourceRange.Copy destRange ' Copy the row to destination sheet
            sourceRange.Delete ' Delete the row from source sheet
        End If
    Next i
  
    destWB.Save
    destWB.Close
  
End Sub
```

Comment: What's up with the workbook open being done at the bottom? I presume you want to do that first?

Comment: Whenever I put that code at the top, the macro opens the destination workbook and then doesnt run the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

modify accordingly:

```
Sub CopyRowsToDestination()
    Dim sourceWB As Workbook
    Dim sourceWS As Worksheet
    Dim destWB As Workbook
    Dim destWS As Worksheet
    Dim sourceRange As Range
    Dim destRange As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    Set sourceWB = ThisWorkbook ' Replace with the name of the source workbook
    Set sourceWS = sourceWB.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' Replace with the name of the source worksheet
    Set destWB = Workbooks("destination.xlsx") ' Replace with the name of the destination workbook
    Set destWS = destWB.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' Replace with the name of the destination worksheet
    lastRow = sourceWS.Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row ' Determine the last row in column J
    
    For i = lastRow To 1 Step -1 ' Loop through the range backwards to avoid skipping rows after deletion
        If sourceWS.Cells(i, "J").Value = "remove" Then
            Set sourceRange = sourceWS.Rows(i)
            Set destRange = destWS.Cells(destWS.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) ' Determine the first empty row in destination sheet
            sourceRange.Copy destRange ' Copy the row to destination sheet
            sourceRange.Delete ' Delete the row from source sheet
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```